How to make sure my fork and headset is compatible with a new frame?
I'm considering to buy a new frame to replace my old and defected Merida Big Seven 100 27.5" MTB frame. I'm going to buy the new frame online as the store is very far from me. I couldn't make any sense of the dimensions they provide for the headset which is ø28.6ø41.8ø52*ø30, H:13mm.
I took the measure of the diameter of bearings of my current headset. It is around 38 mm for both top and bottom one. The fork is a SR Suntour 27 XCM HLO 100.
Attached is the photo of the frame I consider to buy
.

This frame will be tapered with the upper diameter 1+1/8". If your fork is not tapered 1+1/2", it won't fit. But I do not know the meaning of all the numbers. 13 mm will be the lenght of the head tube.

The existing fork can be made to fit using the proper crown race. (1 1/8" to 1 1/2") @VladimirFГероямслава. That's as long as the fork steerer is a good length for the new frame.

The proposed frame is designed for a fork with a tapered steer tube, which is 1⅛" (28.6mm) at the top where the stem attaches, and at the fork crown, the steer tube has grown to 1½" (or nearly 40mm).  As mentioned in the comments, one can fit a fork with an 1⅛" straight steer tube in a frame designed for a tapered steer tube by installing a special reducer fork crown race on the straight steer tube fork. The "reducing" aspect is that it allows the use of the larger bearing within the lower headtube (designed for tapered forks that measure 1½" at the crown) to fit nicely on the straight 1⅛" steer tube.
What's interesting about your online bike frame and their stated headset is the numbers they give imply that they are providing a reducer crown race with their headset. See, the other dimensions are for a tapered headtube (and that is what is shown in your photo) except for the ∅52*∅30. The 30 refers to a crown race sized for a straight, 1⅛" steer tube.  A headset for a tapered head tube/tapered fork would read 52/40.  I realize this may be confusing.  The numbers the bike manufacturer gives for the the headset represent a partial version of what's known as Standardized Headset Identification System (SHIS). This is a way for various manufacturers of bikes and the various providers of headsets to speak a common language in regard to what headset is required for any particular bike. It also has information regarding the required size and type (straight or tapered) of fork steerer tube will work the headset & frame.
I'm going to refer you to a website tutorial that handles this topic very clearly. The lowdown on headset nomenclature is given by Park Tool in their S.H.I.S. Headset Identification System tutorial.  Essentially, the letters within the SHIS refers to a type of headset and that is dependent on the design of a bike's head tube.  The numbers represent the diameters of the pertinent parts involved, namely, the internal diameter of the bike headtube (coincides with the outside diameter of the cartridge bearing used at that part of the headtube) and the outside diameter of the fork steer tube or crown race seat of the steer tube (the lowest part of the steerer tube, exposed just above the fork crown). These measurements coincide with the internal diameter of the cartridge bearing used at the upper and lower head tube respectively.
To sum up, the numbers given by the bike manufacturer in your photo translate into SHIS form as: IS42/28.6|IS52/30.  If you read the tutorial I linked to, you'll learn the first set of letters/numbers represent the upper headset (41.8 is rounded to 42 in SHIS), while the second set speak to the bottom (the 30 is a rounded up 28.7 and is actually very nearly the outer diameter of the lowest part of the steer tube--aka crown race seat, as well as the inner diameter of the crown race).  The H:13 is the stack height in millimeters of that portion of the headset.

Thank you for your answer. All I need is an adapter that will take the slack at the bottom end of the headset, right? Like this one: https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/ikinci-el-ve-sifir-alisveris-spor-bisiklet-duz-konik-masa-cevirici-adaptor-sifir-1196371468/detay

Yes, but based on the numbers they gave you (the ones in your question), it appears it may be provided. This is based on the "∅52 ∅30" Where 52 is the inside diameter of the headtube and 30 is (presumably) the inner diameter of bearing and crown race of the lower headset.  Typically a 52mm I D.  headtube, designed for a tapered steerer, will have a 40mm ID bearing & crown race for the 1.5" taper of the steerer. 30 is the measurement for a straight 1⅛" steerer.  Overall, yes, you should only need the reducing crown race

I can't open your link for some reason. But if you've linked to a reducing crown race, that's what you need.  Because the manufacturer hasn't given the headset numbers in a strict SHIS format, there is a question as to what they mean by the 30.

They don't provide a reducer crown race so I gave up on it. Thanks again.
